# how to implement a numeric prefix argument in emacs

Tags: prefix-argument

When I press "d", this loop runs 52 times.
How can I adjust this elisp so that, I can specify a number
instead of harcoding 52.

I guess I'm trying to do something like " C-u -1 C-x ^" mentioned at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindowResize

```
;; comment                                                                                                                     
(eval-after-load 'elfeed-search
  '(define-key elfeed-search-mode-map "d" #'my/elfeed-extra-info))                                                             

;; fetches extra info                                                                                                          
(defun my/elfeed-extra-info ()
  (interactive)
  (dotimes (i 52)
    (elfeed-goto-line i)                                                                       
    (my/detect-country (elfeed-search-selected :ignore-region))
    (my/detect-isfp      (elfeed-search-selected :ignore-region))
    (my/detect-others (elfeed-search-selected :ignore-region))
    (elfeed-search-update :force)                                                                                                                               
    )                                                                                                                          
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the number of times as the numeric prefix arg. See the Elisp manual, node [Prefix Command Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html) and node [Using `interactive'](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html).

```el
(defun my/elfeed-extra-info (&optional numtimes) ; <=== Add an argument
  (interactive "p") ; <=== Supply numeric prefix arg interactively
  (dotimes (i  numtimes)
    (elfeed-goto-line i)                                                                       
    (my/detect-country (elfeed-search-selected :ignore-region))
    (my/detect-isfp (elfeed-search-selected :ignore-region))
    (my/detect-others (elfeed-search-selected :ignore-region))
    (elfeed-search-update :force)))
```

---

UPDATE after your new request (you really should edit your question, or better yet, pose a new question rather than changing the request):

```el
(defun my/elfeed-extra-info (&optional numtimes)
  (interactive (list (if current-prefix-arg ; <=== User provided arg
                         (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)
                       52))) ; <=== Default
  (dotimes (i  numtimes)
    (elfeed-goto-line i)                                                                       
    (my/detect-country (elfeed-search-selected :ignore-region))
    (my/detect-isfp (elfeed-search-selected :ignore-region))
    (my/detect-others (elfeed-search-selected :ignore-region))
    (elfeed-search-update :force)))
```

Comment: can I still press d and emacs uses 52 as a default

Comment: Updated to answer that.